# How to clear the contents of cell B based on value of cell A

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hi I am trying to figure out the following specific example:

If cell C19 AND C21 both equal "NO"
then any values in cells C24:C26 will be deleted.

If either C19 or C21 equal "Yes"
then C24:C26 are not affected

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty much the answer.

"If cell C19 AND C21 both equal "NO" then any values in cells C24:C26 will be deleted."

If, then, else is the basic format for a lot of scripting.

IF C19 AND C21 = "NO" then C24:C26 = Empty

Now just add the scripting language so the computer can understand you.
.

```
If activesheet.range("C19").value = "NO" AND activesheet.range("C21").value = "NO" then
activesheet.range("C24:C26").ClearContents
end if
```

Now you can add a trap for user error by making sure the variable in question is in uppercase like this: So if C21 = "no" instead of "NO" it will still work with the UCase function

```
If UCase(activesheet.range("C19").value) = "NO" AND UCase(activesheet.range("C21").value) = "NO" then
activesheet.range("C24:C26").ClearContents
end if
```